# Passing a $_SESSION failed when creating the $_SESSION within Ajax function

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a simple registration form and the new comers will be registered with an ajax function. There I create a `$_SESSION['is_logged']` when the registration is finished.
On var_dumb I get that the var is set. But when redirect on another page it is empty (I have included already the session_start() on the both pages...
I have read somewhere in the net that:

> "Sessions are ONLY written on a page load/refresh".

Is this the case, or I have to look for some other issues within my code.

the ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
        url:"../controllers/register.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:res,
        success: function(responce){
            if (responce==1) {
                $('#msg').addClass('msg-warning');
                $("#form").css('display',"none");
                $('#msg').append("<p>It seems that you have already submited the form. Click to "+
                    " <a href='login.php'>log-in</a> or to <a href='register.php'>register</a>.</p>");
            }
            else if (responce==2) {
                $('#msg').addClass('msg-warning');
                $("#form").css('display',"none");
                $('#msg').append("<p>You have successfully created account. Click to "+
                    " <a href='start.php'>welcome</a> to start your .</p>");
                $('.menu').append("<li><a href='logout.php'>Log out</a></li>")
            }
            else{
                $('#msg').text(responce);
            }

        },
        error: function(){
            $('#msg').text("Opss, try again");
        }
    });
```

the register.php file:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['submited'])) {
    echo 1;
    exit;
}

include_once('../models/functions.php');

// Give the post parametters to another var
$arr=$_POST;

// function for uploading
$reg = registerMe($arr);

if ($reg === true) {
    $_SESSION['submited']=1;
    $_SESSION['is_logged']=1    
    echo(2);
}   
else{
    echo($reg); 
}
exit;
```

The `session_start();` is included in the header of the first page where from the ajax is started.And the second page - where the $_SESSION['is_logged'] is lost, again the `session_start()`; is part of `dc_header();` function. start.php:

```
<?php
dc_header("Речник|Регистрация");

if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged'])) {
    #header("location: ../views/login.php");
    var_dump($_SESSION);
}
```

?>

Comment: please post the ajax code

Comment: Logically it should work. Post code where you are setting the value and where you are getting to check and redirect.

Comment: is the redirected page on a different subdomain then the one you are using with the ajax call? www.url.com and url.com are considered by browsers to be different subdomains so the sessions are different for each one.

Comment: Post the code of `start.php` where you are checking the `is_logged` in session.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($_SESSION);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
session_start();
```

to the top of register.php

You need to specify session_start, so your server who was commanded to execute "register.php" (either from ajax, direct call, browser scripts, cron job or whatever possible you-name-it) will handle the execution and the setting of $_SESSION variables in reference to the connected clients session. Server won't guess by itself that this is an "ajax call from an already session_start page". You need to specify that whatever is done in register.php is done in the current client's session.

Comment: damn, it worked. So nevertheless that i have once included the session_start() in the header of the page once i perform an ajax query, i need to declare again the session_start().

Comment: @Alordiel anything that is about a user, must be in his session. so, you start with session_start. Imagine this: if you have logout with ajax, lets say ajax_log_out.php you can see that it is vital to have session_start (otherwise which user to log-out??) happy to help :)